# rails AWS S3 delete file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services

I do uploads to amazon S3 with carrierwave that works fine.

But Now I want to add a delete function I tried this:

```
AWS::S3::S3Object.delete(@vid.video, 'bucket')
```

I got this error:

```
uninitialized constant MoviesController::AWS
```

The reason is clear .. But how do I set the AWS constant correctly and where?

**config/initializers/carrierwave.rb**

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id => '----',
    :aws_secret_access_key => '----',
    :region => 'eu-central-1',
}
config.fog_use_ssl_for_aws = false
config.fog_directory = 'bucekt'
config.storage = :fog
end
```

Comment: Have you added the `AWS SDK gem` to your `Gemfile`?

Comment: yes I have done this

Comment: I am not sure but you also need to configure the `AWS` gem in your code. My gut feeling is it's not autoloading but it should.

Comment: And how do I do this correctly? I've only set it up at carrierwave initializer

Comment: Can you add the carrierwave code that is setting it up? Plus filenames etc?

Comment: of course. added above.

Comment: did you restart your server after installing aws-sdk gem ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must first configure the `AWS` gem. Add this code to the `config/initializers/aws.rb` file.

```
Aws.config.update({
  region: '<default-region>',
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new('<access-key-id>', '<secret-access-key')
})
```

You can also set the environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, and `AWS_REGION` on your server and the `SDK` will pick them up automatically.

Then, anywhere in your app or a controller action, you can call the `S3 API` like this:

```
def some_action
  # You can simply call Aws::S3::Client.new
  # if you are already configuring using the
  # above methods or configure by passing
  # parameters explicitly
  s3_client = Aws::S3::Client.new(
    credentials: Aws::Credentials.new('<aws_access_key_id>', '<aws_secret_key>'),
    region: '<aws_region>'
  )

  # delete object by passing bucket and object key
  s3_response = s3_client.delete_object({
    bucket: '<bucket-name>', # required
    key: '<object-key>', # required
  })
end
```

Comment: when I set the  Aws. in aws.rb ... why do I have to set the Credentials again on s3_client ?

Comment: where do I set the s3_client = ... code? in aws.rb or where?

Comment: thanks! ... I've done it it looks like it works, but the file in S3 isn't deleted ...

Comment: What response do you get from the call?

Comment: #<struct Aws::S3::Types::DeleteObjectOutput delete_marker=nil, version_id=nil, request_charged=nil>

Comment: Well, if the code is working without any errors, I think your question has been answered. It would take further analysis to understand why a successful request is not deleting the said object.

Comment: as object key I put @video.video.to_s is that correct?

Comment: Check your bucket and the key you are trying to delete. Is it there? Debug the code and see what keys are being sent for the delete call. Verify that all parameters are correct.

Comment: @Felix If you think your initial question is answered(which I think it is), you can also mark the answer and upvote. Thanks.

Comment: when I Upload the file is put in bucket xyz and the path is xyz/uploads/movie/video/ID

Comment: `bucket` would be `xyz` and `key` would be `uploads/movie/video/ID` for the delete function.